# Python 2.7 - Tkinter user entry prompt

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

Okay, so I'm attempting to deploy a Tkinter prompt into my script to simply read the user entry into the `ROOTDIR` variable.

Below is a Tkinter script that seems ideal for what I'm attempting to accomplish, but having trouble tying the script into my base script also found below.

```
import Tkinter as tk

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.entry = tk.Entry(self)
        self.button = tk.Button(self, text="Please enter path", command=self.on_button)
        self.button.pack()
        self.entry.pack()

    def on_button(self):
        print self.entry.get()

app = SampleApp()
app.mainloop()
```

Below is the base program that I'm attempting include a Tkinter prompt with.

```
import glob
import os
import xlrd
import csv

#set data path
ROOTDIR = r'C:\Users\username\Desktop\Mults'
wb_pattern = os.path.join(ROOTDIR, '*.xlsx')

workbooks = glob.glob(wb_pattern)
start_rownum = 3 # number of row eliminated
with open('merged excel.csv', 'wb') as outcsv:
writer = csv.writer(outcsv)
for wb in workbooks:
    book_path = os.path.join(ROOTDIR, wb)
    book =  xlrd.open_workbook(book_path)
    sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)
    for row_num in xrange(start_rownum, sheet.nrows):
        row = sheet.row_values(row_num)
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Any assistance is much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: You say you're having trouble. What sort of trouble are you having? Also, the indentation of your code is messed up.

Comment: @BryanOakley I'm having trouble understanding how to use Tkinter with my script

Comment: why can you not copy/paste the top code into your base code? if you need the user input, where is that needed?

Comment: @W1ll1amvl that's where I'm stuck. Trying to intertwine that top code into the base code

Comment: I will post an answer and you can see if it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is an almost straight copy paste, it should work? only change was to set `ROOTDIR` as entry from tk window and write the rest in a function so you can call it once `ROOTDIR` is created.

```
import glob
import os
import xlrd
import csv
import Tkinter as tk

def maincode():
    global ROOTDIR
    wb_pattern = os.path.join(ROOTDIR, '*.xlsx')

    workbooks = glob.glob(wb_pattern)
    start_rownum = 3 # number of row eliminated
    with open('merged excel.csv', 'wb') as outcsv:
    writer = csv.writer(outcsv)
    for wb in workbooks:
        book_path = os.path.join(ROOTDIR, wb)
        book =  xlrd.open_workbook(book_path)
        sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)
        for row_num in xrange(start_rownum, sheet.nrows):
            row = sheet.row_values(row_num)
            writer.writerow(row)

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.entry = tk.Entry(self)
        self.button = tk.Button(self, text="Please enter path", command=self.on_button)
        self.button.pack()
        self.entry.pack()

    def on_button(self):
        global ROOTDIR
        ROOTDIR = self.entry.get()
        maincode()

app = SampleApp()
app.mainloop()
```

if this doesn't work get back to me :)